# array_push is alway put my array at index

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a question about array_push in PHP. Now I'm trying to put one array into another array but it is alway put it into index[0].

Please take a look on screenshot. I want array [link] to be same level as [comment] but I have no idea why it is alway in [0] array.

Please check on my code at line 39-40.

Thanks for advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might set it directly to the `$result` array by using "link" as the key

```
$result["link"] = $link_captured;
```

Or set the array `$r`

```
$r = [
        "link" => "test linek"
];

$result["link"] = $r;
```

In your `foreach`, you have an `if` `else` statement that in both cases run `array_push($result, $t);`

You could move that after the if else and write it only once.